# Word for doing something all of a sudden not by any influence

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, idiom-requests

Some political party has passed some law and a group of people is out on the streets celebrating. These people are probably affiliated to the party and do not represent the entire population.

'I've never seen people celebrate the passing of a law,' said dragonfly.

'You can't assume the celebrations are_____,' countered lonewolf.

Comment: Lonewolf could say that 'correlation does not imply causation'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Merriam Webster defines ***Spontaneous*** as:

> 1 : proceeding from natural feeling or native tendency without external constraint.
>   2 : arising from a momentary impulse.
>   3 : controlled and directed internally: SELF-ACTING <~ movement characteristic of living things>.
>   4 : produced without being planted or without human labor: INDIGENOUS
>   5 : developing or occurring without apparent external influence, force, cause, or treatment.
>   6 : not apparently contrived or manipulated: NATURAL

I think all of these (with the exception of 4) are applicable in your case.

Comment: Great minds think alike!

Answer (score 1):

I have two suggestions.  For the way you've worded your sample sentence, I like ***spontaneous***:

> ***[spontaneous](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/spontaneous)***
>
> ADJECTIVE
>
> 1. Performed or occurring as a result of a sudden impulse or inclination and without premeditation or external stimulus.
>      *‘the audience broke into spontaneous applause’*
>      *‘a spontaneous display of affection’*
>
>    1.1 Having an open, natural, and uninhibited manner.
>
>    1.2 (of a process or event) occurring without apparent external cause.
>       *‘spontaneous miscarriages’*

So your sentence would be:

> 'You can't assume the celebrations are ***spontaneous***,' countered lonewolf.

The second option is ***impromptu***:

> ***[impromptu](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/impromptu)***
>
> ADJECTIVE & ADVERB
>
> Done without being planned or rehearsed.
>   *[as adjective] ‘an impromptu press conference’*
>   *[as adverb] ‘he spoke impromptu’*

It's just personal preference, I think, but I would use *impromptu* thusly:

> 'You can't assume these are ***impromptu*** celebrations,' countered lonewolf.